# How to show headers and their values correctly in pivotable.js

Tags: javascript, pivot-table, pivottable.js

I am trying to make a [pivotable](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/). I have data structured like this:

```js
["periode", "_alder_5i40s_hrchy_id", "_alder_5i40s_txt", "alder40s_txt", "alder5i_txt", "_rajo_hrchy_id", "_omrade_txt", "_tilb_2ptv_hrchy_id", "_tilb_2ptv_txt", "tilb_2ptv_txt", "tilb_1ptv_txt", "tilb_0ptv_txt", "measc02_1", "measc01_1", "membc02_1"]
["2014M01", "/50/", "40+ år ", "40+ år ", null, "/1/", "RAR Hovedstaden", "/10/", "Vejledning og opkvalificering i alt ", "Vejledning og opkvalificering i alt ", null, null, "69", "63", "1"], ["2015M01", "/50/", "40+ år ", "40+ år ", null, "/1/", "RAR Hovedstaden", "/10/", "Vejledning og opkvalificering i alt ", "Vejledning og opkvalificering i alt ", null, null, "399", "356", "1"], ["2014M01", "/50/", "40+ år ", "40+ år ", null, "/1/", "RAR Hovedstaden", "/40/700/", "Privat virksomhedspraktik  ", "Virksomhedspraktik i alt", "Privat virksomhedspraktik  ", null, "5", "5", "1"], ["2015M01", "/50/", "40+ år ", "40+ år ", null, "/1/", "RAR Hovedstaden", "/40/700/", "Privat virksomhedspraktik  ", "Virksomhedspraktik i alt", "Privat virksomhedspraktik  ", null, "39", "38", "1"],
```

With the last 3 fields being the values to be displayed in the table. The problem is that I have 3      values for each line and I can't figure out how to display that with the text from the header as well.

Is the only solution to split up all the lines in 3 as to have name and the value in the same line? Such as:

```js
["periode", "_alder_5i40s_hrchy_id", "_alder_5i40s_txt", "alder40s_txt", "alder5i_txt", "_rajo_hrchy_id", "_omrade_txt", "_tilb_2ptv_hrchy_id", "_tilb_2ptv_txt", "tilb_2ptv_txt", "tilb_1ptv_txt", "tilb_0ptv_txt", member_name, member_value]
["2014M01", "/50/", "40+ år ", "40+ år ", null, "/1/", "RAR Hovedstaden", "/10/", "Vejledning og opkvalificering i alt ", "Vejledning og opkvalificering i alt ", null, null, measc02_1, "69", ]
```

Or have I overlooked some nice feature that could handle this smarter?

Hope you will help me :)

Code as of now:

```
  $(this.shadowRoot).find("#databanktable").pivotUI(
            [data.header, ...data.data],
            {
                cols : this.tableColumns,
                rows : this.tableRows,
                vals,
                rendererOptions: {
                    table: {
                        colTotals: false,
                        rowTotals: false,
                    },
                },
                showUI: false,
                
                aggregatorName:"List Unique Values",
                rendererName: "Table",
            },true);
```

Comment: Pivot table - Using what plugin? Please post some code in a [mcve] and explain expected and actual output

Comment: Thanks for the edit, were just doing the same thing :D
Plugin? pivotable.js ?

Comment: pivottable.js was taggable.

Comment: Thanks again! Tried that but it didn't show up :)